# Why does vim complain about weak crypto when using blowfish2?

Tags: encryption

I opened up a document from 2015 I saved using the built in crypto in vim (`:X`). That was saves using `blowfish` at the time.

The message I got now (2017) was this:

```
Warning: Using a weak encryption method; see :help 'cm'
Enter encryption key: *********************************************
Enter same key again: *********************************************
```

That was weird, I thought, but I assumed it had to do with some flaw, and after reading up on the crypto methods I `set cryptomethod=blowfish2`. This works after opening it, showing cryptomethod as blowfish 2. The problem is that I still get the message about using weak encryption! Why? Are there remnants of the old blowfish1 crypto signature? Do I have to export the text and resave it in order to fix it?

Comment: Try to encrypt it again with blowfish2 (that only works, if all your vim versions are new enough)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cryptmethod is stored in the file itself, and isn't automatically updated.

You can see this with `less`:

```
$ less a
VimCrypt~02!!<C7>\<E1>wZzm
^E^X^Z<92>5<C9>I6<9C>S
```

`VimCrypt~01!` is `cm=zip`, `VimCrypt~02!` is `cm=blowfish`, and I think you can deduce what `VimCrypt~03!` stands for :-)

To upgrade a file, open it, explicitly set `cm=blowfish2`, and write it:

```
$ vim a
Need encryption key for "a"
Warning: Using a weak encryption method; see :help 'cm'
Enter encryption key: [enter-key]

:set cm?
  cryptmethod=blowfish
:set cm=blowfish2
:w
"a" [blowfish2] 1L, 3C written
:q

$ less a
VimCrypt~03!O[P<D5>1<D1><DA>^Zis<88>q<AB><99><8C><A6><C4><FB>6
a lines 1-1/1 (END)
```